# EntityFramework Sum specifying different timezoneoffset

Tags: entity-framework

In my database I have a basic table that stores, DateTime (All datestimes in UTC in SQL) and Amount.

I need to be able to do a sum (each record in the toList() sum the amount, grouped by the day in the timezone specified.) by day specifying the timezone in entityframework, but I have no idea how to do it.

Theory says if you run the query with offset -5, the actual query is something like from and to day 05:00 AM....

without timezones I would probably do it like this,

```
db.Payments.GroupBy(x => x.TransactionDate)
    .Select(g => new { TransactionDate.Date, Amount = g.Sum(x => x.Amount) });
```

but how would I incorporate a timezone aware sum?